# NSLocale to Country name

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, locale, nslocale

I have seen this answered in objective-C, but I don't know how to convert to swift.

My app receives the public information of a user from Facebook, and I need to convert the locale into the country name.

```
FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler({
            connection, result, error in    
            user["locale"] = result["locale"]
            user["email"] = result["email"]
            user.save()

            println(result.locale)


        })
```

For example, for a French user, the code sends "Optional(fr_FR)" to the log. However I need it to just send the country name. According to localeplanet.com, the display name of "fr_FR" is "French (France)". So in the log all I want is "France".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Working off of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6177309/2274694), I've whipped up a Swift translation. Try this:

```
let locale: NSLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: result.locale!)
let countryCode = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as String
var country: String? = locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode, value: countryCode)

// According to the docs, "Not all locale property keys
// have values with display name values" (thus why the 
// "country" variable's an optional). But if this one
// does have a display name value, you can print it like so.
if let foundCounty = country {
    print(foundCounty)
}
```

Updated for Swift 4:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"locale"]).start { (connection, result, error) in

    guard let resultDictionary = result as? [String:Any], 
          let localeIdentifier = resultDictionary["locale"] as? String else {
        return
    }

    let locale: NSLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: localeIdentifier)

    if let countryCode = locale.object(forKey: NSLocale.Key.countryCode) as? String,
       let country = locale.displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.countryCode, value: countryCode) {
        print(country)
    }
}
```