# Swift -How to show a UIPickerView with multi strings per line (not components)

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm not looking for a multiple component pickerView, I'm looking for 1 pickerView with multi strings per line.

I have a dictionary of country codes (keys) and the matching dialing codes (values).

I loop through the dictionary and [use this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408473/4833705) to get the country from the key. The country is a String.

As I loop I also [use this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30403199/4833705) to get the emoji flag of each country. The emoji flag is a String.

Now that I have all 4 values for each country (the flag, country name, country code, and dialing code), how can I add the corresponding 3 of the 4 values to each line of a pickerView (the flag, country name, and dialing code). The pickerView should look like this:

[image]

I'm going to need to access the country name, country code, and dialing code (3 of the 4 values) inside the pickerView's `didSelect`.

```
let phoneNumberTextField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField()
    return textField
}()

let pickerView = UIPickerView()

var countries = [String]()
var flags = [String]()

var arrOfCountriesWithTheirValues = [???]()

let dialingCodes = ["AF": "93", "AE": "971", "AL": "355", "AN": "599", "AS":"1", "AD": "376", "AO": "244", "AI": "1", "AG":"1", "AR": "54","AM": "374", "AW": "297", "AU":"61", "AT": "43","AZ": "994", "BS": "1", "BH":"973", "BF": "226","BI": "257", "BD": "880", "BB": "1", "BY": "375", "BE":"32","BZ": "501", "BJ": "229", "BM": "1", "BT":"975", "BA": "387", "BW": "267", "BR": "55", "BG": "359", "BO": "591", "BL": "590", "BN": "673", "CC": "61", "CD":"243","CI": "225", "KH":"855", "CM": "237", "CA": "1", "CV": "238", "KY":"345", "CF":"236", "CH": "41", "CL": "56", "CN":"86","CX": "61", "CO": "57", "KM": "269", "CG":"242", "CK": "682", "CR": "506", "CU":"53", "CY":"537","CZ": "420", "DE": "49", "DK": "45", "DJ":"253", "DM": "1", "DO": "1", "DZ": "213", "EC": "593", "EG":"20", "ER": "291", "EE":"372","ES": "34", "ET": "251", "FM": "691", "FK": "500", "FO": "298", "FJ": "679", "FI":"358", "FR": "33", "GB":"44", "GF": "594", "GA":"241", "GS": "500", "GM":"220", "GE":"995","GH":"233", "GI": "350", "GQ": "240", "GR": "30", "GG": "44", "GL": "299", "GD":"1", "GP": "590", "GU": "1", "GT": "502", "GN":"224","GW": "245", "GY": "595", "HT": "509", "HR": "385", "HN":"504", "HU": "36", "HK": "852", "IR": "98", "IM": "44", "IL": "972", "IO":"246", "IS": "354", "IN": "91", "ID":"62", "IQ":"964", "IE": "353","IT":"39", "JM":"1", "JP": "81", "JO": "962", "JE":"44", "KP": "850", "KR": "82","KZ":"77", "KE": "254", "KI": "686", "KW": "965", "KG":"996","KN":"1", "LC": "1", "LV": "371", "LB": "961", "LK":"94", "LS": "266", "LR":"231", "LI": "423", "LT": "370", "LU": "352", "LA": "856", "LY":"218", "MO": "853", "MK": "389", "MG":"261", "MW": "265", "MY": "60","MV": "960", "ML":"223", "MT": "356", "MH": "692", "MQ": "596", "MR":"222", "MU": "230", "MX": "52","MC": "377", "MN": "976", "ME": "382", "MP": "1", "MS": "1", "MA":"212", "MM": "95", "MF": "590", "MD":"373", "MZ": "258", "NA":"264", "NR":"674", "NP":"977", "NL": "31","NC": "687", "NZ":"64", "NI": "505", "NE": "227", "NG": "234", "NU":"683", "NF": "672", "NO": "47","OM": "968", "PK": "92", "PM": "508", "PW": "680", "PF": "689", "PA": "507", "PG":"675", "PY": "595", "PE": "51", "PH": "63", "PL":"48", "PN": "872","PT": "351", "PR": "1","PS": "970", "QA": "974", "RO":"40", "RE":"262", "RS": "381", "RU": "7", "RW": "250", "SM": "378", "SA":"966", "SN": "221", "SC": "248", "SL":"232","SG": "65", "SK": "421", "SI": "386", "SB":"677", "SH": "290", "SD": "249", "SR": "597","SZ": "268", "SE":"46", "SV": "503", "ST": "239","SO": "252", "SJ": "47", "SY":"963", "TW": "886", "TZ": "255", "TL": "670", "TD": "235", "TJ": "992", "TH": "66", "TG":"228", "TK": "690", "TO": "676", "TT": "1", "TN":"216","TR": "90", "TM": "993", "TC": "1", "TV":"688", "UG": "256", "UA": "380", "US": "1", "UY": "598","UZ": "998", "VA":"379", "VE":"58", "VN": "84", "VG": "1", "VI": "1","VC":"1", "VU":"678", "WS": "685", "WF": "681", "YE": "967", "YT": "262","ZA": "27" , "ZM": "260", "ZW":"263"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self

    phoneNumberTextField.delegate = self

    phoneNumberTextField.inputView = pickerView

    for (key, value) in dialingCodes {

        if let country = countryName(countryCode: key) {

            countries.append(country)

            let emojiFlag = flag(country: key)

            flags.append(emojiFlag)

            // arrOfCountriesWithTheirValues.append(???)
        }
    }
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return arrOfCountriesWithTheirValues.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return arrOfCountriesWithTheirValues[row] 
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    let threeValues = arrOfCountriesWithTheirValues[row]
}

func countryName(countryCode: String) -> String? {
    let current = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    return current.localizedString(forRegionCode: countryCode)
}

func flag(country: String) -> String {
    let base : UInt32 = 127397
    var s = ""
    for v in country.unicodeScalars {
        s.unicodeScalars.append(UnicodeScalar(base + v.value)!)
    }
    return String(s)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `titleForRow`, implement [`viewForRow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614389-pickerview). Now you are free to put anything you like into the view shown on each row of the component.

> I'm going to need to access the country name, country code, and dialing code (3 of the 4 values) inside the pickerView's didSelect.

Fine, but note that that has *nothing* to do with what is *displayed* in the picker view. The picker view is *view*. When you need the data for a selected row, you look in the *model*. You need to revise your model so that every item in the array contains *all* the information you need.