# How to get country's name in country's main language?

Tags: ios, locale

I'm trying to find a country's name in its main language, using [Locale](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/locale).

I am not talking about the iPhone's language, but the language that's mainly spoken in that country.

Let's say I get name of Spain thanks to `Locale`, like that:

```
let spain = Locale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode: "ES")
print(spain)
```

If my iPhone is set up in English, I'll see:

> Spain

What I want is the Spanish name of Spain (España):

> España

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: how we can get, locale give the region of the device

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177309/nslocale-and-country-name

Comment: Cool thanks, and would there be a way to get this language identifier from the country code? I mean, is there a way to get `en_US` from `US`?